# Change the colour of a subset of labels in barplot R

Tags: r, plot, colors, label, customization

I am trying to adjust my barplot so that only a few of the labels appear in a different colour. I know that there was a similar question before ([Change the color of a subset of group labels in a boxplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385219/change-the-color-of-a-subset-of-group-labels-in-a-boxplot-in-r)) but the answer did not help me and everything else I found online neither, so I would really, really appreciate some help.

My data looks like this:

```
trait2 <- c('A','B','C','D')
rg <- c (0.5480, 0.4801, 0.2805, -0.2480)
se <- c(0.0495, 0.0908, 0.0548, 0.0957)
data <- data.frame(trait2,rg,se)
data
 trait2   rg      se
 A       0.5480  0.0495
 B       0.4801  0.0908
 C       0.2805  0.0548
 D       -0.2480  0.0957
```

and the code for the barplot looks like this:

```
barplot1 <- barplot(data$rg,
main="correlation between traits",
xlab="rG",  
border="blue", 
las=1, 
horiz=TRUE, 
names.arg=data$trait2, 
font.axis=2
cex.names=0.5,
xlim=range(-0.4,0.6,0.1) )
```

[image]

I would now like to change the colour of the lables of A and C, but B and D should stay in black.

I tried this, as it was described in the link I mentioned above:

```
mtext(barplot1$trait2, at = 1:length(barplot1$trait2, side=1, line=1,  
col=ifelse(barplot$trait1=="A", "red", "black")))
```

but then I get the error "Error in barplot$trait2 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. Which makes sense, but I still don't know how to solve it.

There was another suggestion of using

```
 + scale_colour_manual(values = c("B" = "red"))
```

which I cannot really make sense of. (Where should I insert that?)

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: `scale_colour_manual()` is a function from the package `ggplot2`. That package gives you more flexible ways of creating charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
barplot1 <- barplot(data$rg,
                    main="correlation between traits",
                    xlab="rG",  
                    border="blue", 
                    las=1, 
                    horiz=TRUE, 
                    font.axis=2,
                    cex.names=0.5,
                    xlim=range(-0.4,0.6,0.1))

axis(2, at = barplot1[c(1,3)], labels = data$trait2[c(1,3)], col.axis = 2)
axis(2, at = barplot1[c(2,4)], labels = data$trait2[c(2,4)], col.axis = 1)
```

[image]

in ggplot you can try

```
 ggplot(data, aes(trait2, rg)) + 
   geom_col(colour="blue", fill="grey") +
   coord_flip() +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = rep(c(2,1),2), size=20))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much!! With the "las=1" argument, I also turned the labels by 90° in the barplot() example. In my real data, the labels are actually a lot longer than only single letters (I only posted the example like this for simplicity). Before I adjusted the fondsize of the labels with "cex.names=0.5" within the barplot function. That does not seem to work using axis(). Do you have any idea how to adjust the font-size with axis() as well?

And I know, I should probably switch to ggplot2, I just have some problems installing it, thats why I stick to barplot() for now.

Comment: @Nora try `cex.axis=2` to set the size of the lables

Answer (score -1):

Use `ggplot` much easier and more elegant than the built in plotting library.  The `scale_color_manual` and `scale_fill_manual` can be inserted within the ggplot code.  Read up on it here (http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html).

Here's an example to color the bars.

```
library(tidyverse) #this package contains many other useful packages included ggplot    

data <- tibble(total = c(5, 6, 4, 3), month = c("april", "may", "june", "july")  
# tibble is used to create a type of data.frame object.

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = month, y = total, fill = type)) +
  geom_col()
```

Its the "fill" arguement that changes the color.  The "color" argument is used for graph objects like lines and points.